# Android Studio - How to debug an AAR file?

Tags: android

I would like to debug my Android project and at the same time also debug the associated AAR file to determine what is taking place.
I have searched and couldn't find a good tutorial on such task.

How may I proceed?

Could you assist me?

Thanks,

Comment: There's no limitation to debug those classes inside the AAR file. Just put a breakpoint and ***navigate into*** the library to the point you want to reach.

Comment: Thank you,
When in Android Studio, I can see under my android  project file various classes, as well as the various subfolders under the "res" folder.
However, under the imported AAR file, I see no sub folders of any kind where I could go and place a break point

Comment: I have browsed the AAR file content with a Java Decompiler.
Just thinking about it, am I required to have the source code utilized to create the AAR file I would like to debug?

Comment: @olivier I know it's been a long time but were you ever able to resolve this? I have the same need.